# open a pdf file in browser from vb

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to open a pdf file from vb using:

```
Diagnostics.Process.Start("file:///H:/Filename.pdf")
```

It opens using the PDF application.
I want it to open in the default browser using the browsers pdf viewer.
Thanks

Comment: I suspect you will need to (1) identify the default browser, (2) get its path (probably from the registry), and (3) invoke it's exe and pass the URL (in quotes) as an argument.

Comment: Or, add the path to the PDF file in a minified HTML document and `Start()` that.